# preferential attachment into network

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to create some nodes and some function for them using NetLogo.  Nodes in my code have an acceptance rate. This criteria shows that nodes, after giving link, reduce their rate of links acceptance. Each new node(last-turtle) in the model checks the acceptance rate of old nodes and the top-5 nodes based on their degree (count my-links) and then link to it.

I have a problem with this procedure: nodes can't check the degree of top 5 nodes. Here is the code:

```
to make-edge
if connection-strategy = "progressive" [
ask turtles [
if sum [count my-links] of turtles >= 1  [ set acceptance-rate 1 ]
if count my-links >= 10 [ set acceptance-rate 0.8]
if count my-links >= 20 [ set acceptance-rate 0.6]
if count my-links >= 30 [ set acceptance-rate 0.4]
if count my-links >= 40 [ set acceptance-rate 0.2] ]

ask last-turtle [
let top-5 sort-on [ count my-in-links ] max-n-of 5 turtles [ count my-in-links ]
show-results top-5 "Top five turtles using max-n-of:"
let sorted-turtles sort-on [ count my-in-links ] turtles
set top-5 n-of 5 sorted-turtles 
if (random-float 1 < acceptance-rate) and (random-float 1 <= prob-of-linkage)  [
create-link-from top-5  [  set color green ]
move-to top-5
fd 1] ] ]

 if connection-strategy = "indifferent" [    
 ask last-turtle [
 let candidate one-of turtles with [ count my-links > 0 ]
 if  (random-float 1 <= prob-of-linkage)  [
 set candidate one-of turtles with [ (count my-links) > 0]
 create-link-from candidate [  set color green ]
 move-to candidate
 fd 1
 ]]]

 end
 to show-results [ turtle-list title ]
 print title
 foreach turtle-list [ t -> ask t [ show count my-in-links ] ]
 end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a bit of a guess what you mean by "nodes can't check the degree of top 5". I think you mean that the correct nodes are being identified (those with highest degree) but the acceptance rate isn't working as you expect.

Here is a cleaner version of your code, with the irrelevant `connection-strategy = "indifferent"` code block removed, and indenting that shows the code block structure.

```
to make-edge
  if connection-strategy = "progressive"
  [ ask turtles
    [ if sum [count my-links] of turtles >= 1  [ set acceptance-rate 1 ]
      if count my-links >= 10 [ set acceptance-rate 0.8]
      if count my-links >= 20 [ set acceptance-rate 0.6]
      if count my-links >= 30 [ set acceptance-rate 0.4]
      if count my-links >= 40 [ set acceptance-rate 0.2]
    ]

    ask last-turtle
    [ let top-5 sort-on [ count my-in-links ] max-n-of 5 turtles [ count my-in-links ]
      show-results top-5 "Top five turtles using max-n-of:"
      let sorted-turtles sort-on [ count my-in-links ] turtles
      set top-5 n-of 5 sorted-turtles
      if (random-float 1 < acceptance-rate) and (random-float 1 <= prob-of-linkage)
      [ create-link-from top-5 [ set color green ]
        move-to top-5
        fd 1
      ]
    ]
  ]

end

to show-results [ turtle-list title ]
  print title
  foreach turtle-list [ t -> ask t [ show count my-in-links ] ]
end
```

You haven't told us what last-turtle is. But, looking at this code, I suspect your problem is in the lines:

```
  if (random-float 1 < acceptance-rate) and (random-float 1 <= prob-of-linkage)
  [ create-link-from top-5 [ set color green ]
```

The acceptance rate being tested is that of last-turtle. I suspect that you actually want the relevant acceptance rate to be the one owned by the turtle that last-turtle wants to connect to.

The way a preferential attachment algorithm usually works is that a new node is attached to the network, bringing its edges with it. My guess is therefore that last-turtle is the new node and does not have any links. This means that its acceptance rate is 0.

I'm not going to attempt to fix this code as you haven't really provided enough information to know whether my guesses are correct. In particular, what behaviour is occurring and how is that different from what you expect? For example, is the problem that no edges are being created, or that 5 edges are always being created or...?

A couple of side notes:

- top-5 is an agentset of 5 turtles, so I can't work out what you are expecting the `move-to` to do
- you seem to be creating top-5 twice

Please provide some further information and I may be able to provide a better answer.